# Series transistor operation region

Tags: mosfet, nmos

If I have all these series transistors with gate tied together, what is the region of operation of them? I saw multiple times that only one of them is in saturation and all the other is in triode. How can I analyze them?

[image]

Comment: Why? I mean, why would you want to do that? The 3-MOSFET circuit with common gates has no advantage over the 1-MOSFET circuit, and indeed has disadvantages. Please explain why you'd want to consider such a circuit, let alone analyze it.

Comment: Can't you analyze them as a single transistor with N times the gate length?

Answer (score 1):

M2..N will be in triode; M1's region depends on the drain voltage.

If all MOSFETs are similar this is equivalent to a single MOSFET with N times the channel length. If the L & W are different,  first order you can 'normalize' all to equal widths and then the equivalent is the sum of the lengths.

This structure is used in ICs where the design rules limit the maximum length of an individual device, yet a longer device is wanted for output impedance, low currents or matching accuracy.